# Need help finding sum and average

Tags: python

I can't seem to make this program to run. There's no error, there's just nothing showing up when I run it. Any help is appreciated1

```
#Return multiple values

def load():
    name=input("enter a name")
    num1=int(input("Enter num1: "))
    num2=int(input("Enter num2: "))
    num3=int(input("Enter num3: "))
    return name, num1, num2, num3

def calc(num1, num2, num3):
    sum=num1, num2, num3
    avg=sum/3
    return sum, avg

def output(name, num1, num2, num3, avg, sum):
    print("Your name is: ", name)
    print("The 3 numbers are: ", num1, num2, num3)
    print('The sum is: ',sum )
    print("The average is: ", avg)

def main():
    name, num1, num2, num3=load()
    sum, avg=calc(num1, num2, num3)
    output(name, num1, num2, num3, sum, avg)
```

Comment: Enter your code in the edit window, then highlight it and press Ctrl-K to place it properly. That way you won't need a link.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `main()` function, this line will probably throw an exception:

```
sum=num1, num2, num3
avg=sum/3
```

change it to:

```
sum=num1 + num2 + num3
avg=sum/3
```

Comment: Don't use `sum` as a variable name.  It shadows the built-in function.

Answer (score 1):

As a friendly commenter noted earlier, you were not calling your main() routine (see last line). You had also mixed the sequence of `sum` and `avg` calls in the signature of `output`. Furthermore `sum` is a Python built-in function. Avoid those. I used `raw_input` because I'm using Python 2.x, don't let that confuse you.  My use of Python 2.x is also the reason for the extra parentheses you'll see in my output. 
Overall you were very close to a working solution, nice job for a Beginner!

```
#Return multiple values

def load():
    name=raw_input("enter a name: ")
    num1=int(raw_input("Enter num1: "))
    num2=int(raw_input("Enter num2: "))
    num3=int(raw_input("Enter num3: "))
    return name, num1, num2, num3

def calc(num1, num2, num3):
    sum1=num1+num2+num3  # sum is a python keyword
    avg=sum1/3.0 # avoiding integer division in case you are using python 2.x
    return sum1, avg

def output(name, num1, num2, num3,   sum1, avg):
    print("Your name is: ", name)
    print("The 3 numbers are: ", num1, num2, num3)
    print('The sum is: ',sum1 )
    print("The average is: ", avg)

def main():
    name, num1, num2, num3=load()
    sum1, avg=calc(num1, num2, num3)
    output(name, num1, num2, num3, sum1,avg)

main()
```

Output:

```
enter a name: Anton
Enter num1: 1
Enter num2: 2
Enter num3: 3
('Your name is: ', 'Anton')
('The 3 numbers are: ', 1, 2, 3)
('The sum is: ', 6)
('The average is: ', 2.0)
```